# akita angular selectQuery catch 404

Tags: angular, angular-akita, akita

I'm investigating on an alternative to NgRx. And so far Akita is a good bet but I'm struggling with error managing. Sometimes I want an error to be app wide and sometimes I want it to be managed by a component. In the example below I launch a 404 error and I want my component to be aware of this and act accordingly but I can't figure out how. Can you help ?

DummyService (Akita):

```
 get(id: number) {
    this.dummyService.loadByID(id).then((dummy: Dummy) => {
      this.akitaDummyStore.setDummy(dummy);
    })/*.catch((err) => {
      alert(err);
      Here it's working I go inside catch but I don't want it here I want the catch in the component
    })*/;
  }
```

Component :

```
  constructor(
    private akitaDummyQuery: AkitaDummyQuery,
    private akitaDummyService: AkitaDummyService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.akitaDummyQuery.selectEntity(666).subscribe(
      akDummy => {
        if (!akDummy) {
          this.akitaDummyService.get(666);
          return;
        }
        this.dummy= Dummy.parse(akDummy.result);
      },
      error => {
        //here I would like to catch the error in the component in order to display a component level error message. 
        alert(error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I can handle the error like this :

```
this.akitaDummyQuery.selectEntity(id).subscribe(
  akDummy => {
    if (!akDummy) {
      this.akitaDummyService.get(id).catch(err => {
        if (err.statusText === 'Not Found') {

        }
      });
      return;
    }
    this.dummy = Dummy.parse(akDummy.result);
  });
```

But when I do this the akita redux object stays in "loading" state = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to @NetanelBasal I was able to solve my issue, I was doing everything the wrong way :

the akita service

```
export class AkitaDummyService {
  constructor(private akitaDummyStore: AkitaDummyStore, private dummyService: DummyService) {
  }
  get(id: number) {
    return this.dummyService.get(id).pipe(tap((dummy) => this.akitaDummyStore.add(createAkitaDummy(dummy.data))));
  }
}
```

the akita query

```
export class AkitaDummyQuery extends QueryEntity<AkitaDummyState, AkitaDummy> {

  constructor(protected store: AkitaDummyStore) {
    super(store);
  }

  selectEntity<R>(id: getIDType<AkitaDummyState>): Observable<Dummy | any> {
    return super.selectEntity(id).pipe(filter(dummy => !!dummy), map((dummy: AkitaDummy) => Dummy.parse(dummy)));
  }

}
```

the component

```
export class PageDummyComponent implements OnInit {
  dummy: Dummy;

  constructor(
    private akitaDummyQuery: AkitaDummyQuery,
    private akitaDummyService: AkitaDummyService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadDummy(5);
  }


  loadDummy(id) {
    if (!this.akitaDummyQuery.hasEntity(id)) {
      this.akitaDummyService.get(id).subscribe({
        error: (err) => {
          // when 404 do something

        }
      });
    }
    this.akitaDummyQuery.selectEntity(id).subscribe(dummy => this.dummy = dummy);
  }
}
```